# php7. echo with concitional part only returns conditional part not preceeding part

Tags: php

I have recently had to recode an echo statement on to two lines to get it to execute correctly. I was wondering if any one knew why.
Original code:

```
<?php
echo $quantityDiscount['show_qty'] . '<br />' .  (is_numeric($quantityDiscount['discounted_price'])) ? $currencies->display_price($quantityDiscount['discounted_price'], zen_get_tax_rate($products_tax_class_id)) : $quantityDiscount['discounted_price']; ?>
```

New code:

```
<?php 
echo $quantityDiscount['show_qty'] . '<br />';
echo  (is_numeric($quantityDiscount['discounted_price'])) ? $currencies->display_price($quantityDiscount['discounted_price'], zen_get_tax_rate($products_tax_class_id)) : $quantityDiscount['discounted_price']; ?>
```

The original code output "£22.50"

The new code output correctly "3-5<br />£22.50"

Am I missing something or is this a feature of php 7.

Comment: In the first version `$q . '<br>' . is_numeric(...)` is the condition. PHP doesn't know whether you mean `($q . '' . is()) ? :` or `$q . '' . (is() ? :)`.

Comment: @deceze is correct. Wrap the ENTIRE second conditional part, in `( ... )` to make it stick. (*Which I always do out of habit anyhow, so I never noticed this issue come up.*)